TiKz + Beamer : positioning not working as expected
Currently, I am working with Beamer to make some slides based on tikz for decorations.
I am experiencing 2 problems with node positioning:

Cannot place the background to use all of the slide height (see first screenshot)

Already set the margins and text limits for beamer to 0pt.
Q: Is there a limitation by beamer in this sense?


When adding a second node over the background node, the new node is positioned without respecting the tikz definition.

Is TikZ fully compatible with beamer?



Please note that the overall background for the slides is set with beamer separatly, but for the title page I want to use a coloured background.
Source Code:
% Title page
\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{PresentationTpl}[1][] { 

\includegraphics[height=\paperheight, keepaspectratio]
      {images/background/groundstation-large.jpg}

\begin{tikzpicture}{overlay, remember picture}

    \draw (current page.north east) node (__stripe)
    [
        anchor=north east,
        shift={(0cm, 0cm)},
        text=white!95,
        fill=blackRubber,
        minimum width=1.5\stripeW,
        minimum height=1.0\paperheight,
        align=center,
    ]
        {asdfasd};

\end{tikzpicture}

}




I wouldn't use xelatex with beamer. If you need unicode, better use lualatex

Can you make a compilable example which allows us to reproduce your problems?

About 2: tikz and beamer usually work well together, after all they have both been created by the same author and are both based on pgf.

Absolute positioning with TikZ (as used in your tikzpicture code) doesn't work properly with xe[la]tex. As @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz suggests, you should switch to lualatex for this.

I finally made it work by using the node element from TikZ instead of draw.
The example below works both with xelatex and lualatex.
Any directions on why \node works but \draw does not are more than welcomed.
See attached screenshot of the generated PDF file, alignment works just fine.
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary
{
    arrows,
    chains,
    decorations.pathreplacing,
    decorations.text,
    positioning,
    patterns,
    shapes,
    shapes.geometric,
    scopes
}

% %%%%%%%%%%%% widths and heights
\newlength{\stripeW}
\setlength{\stripeW}{0.25\paperwidth}

\setbeamersize{text margin left=0mm, text margin right=0mm}
\geometry{hmargin=0cm, vmargin=0cm, head=0cm, headsep=0pt, foot=0cm}

\setbeamertemplate{background}{
    \includegraphics[height=\paperheight,keepaspectratio]
        {../images/background/groundstation-large-grayscale.jpg}
}

% Title page
\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{PresentationTpl}[1][] { 

    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture] 
        \node (__bg) at (current page.center)
            [anchor=center]
            {
                \includegraphics[height=\paperheight, keepaspectratio]
                    {../images/background/groundstation-large.jpg}
            };
        \node (r) at (current page.north east)
            [rectangle,draw,anchor=north east,color=white,fill=black]
            {Rectangle};
    \end{tikzpicture}

}

\author[rtubio]{\texttt{rtpardavila@gmail.com}}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}\titlepage\end{frame}

\end{document}


